# Archivo de configuracon

Tags: vb.net

Buenas noches, 
quisiera saber si alguno sabe como modificar el ámbito de las variables en VB.net, ya que el ámbito de la cadena de conexión no me permite modificarlo y en el momento lo necesito. 
Gracias
[image: [configuracion]]

Comment: por favor, si no lo hiciste mira [ask].. y a que lo quieres modificar.. y porque?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buenas lurduy,

Las configuraciones de tipo `'Cadena de conexión'` sólo pueden ser de ámbito `Aplicación` en los archivos de configuración, tal y como dice [aquí](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/a65txexh.aspx).

La diferencia que hay entre los 2 `Ámbitos` (`Aplicación` y `Usuario`) son que, las variables de configuración de tipo `Aplicación`, no pueden ser modificadas en tiempo de ejecución, es decir, siempre tendrán el mismo valor, y las variables de configuración de usuario sí pueden ser modificadas en tiempo de ejecución.

Para solucionar el problema que tienes (poco seguro) podrías poner las cadenas de conexión en variables tipo `String` y de ésta manera, sí podrás cambiar el `Ámbito` a tipo `Usuario`.

Comment: Lo estoy probando con string, pero al momento de cerrar y abrir la aplicacion se reinicia la cadena,hay alguna forma de dejarla permanente?

Comment: Si, puedes hacer un `My.Settings.Save()` y se va a guardar la variable para siempre, pero no en tu archivo de configuración del proyecto, sino que se va a guardar en otro archivo ubicado en ProgramData.

Comment: Gracias voy a probar esa opción

Comment: Puedes hacer una sencilla prueba, con un MessageBox imprimiendo la variable que tenias, modificarla, cerrar el programa y al volverlo a abrir volver a llamar MessageBox para que te salga el mensaje con la variable modificada.

Comment: Si señor, probe la cadena de conexión y funciono perfecto con la opción que me diste, muchas gracias.